# [ symbol will no longer be typed in ASPX.CS files

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In any ASPX.CS files, when I press `ALT GR + [`, the code auto-formats. I can no longer type this symbol. What setting controls this?

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: Yes, I even suspended them all, didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Tools, Options, Environment, Keyboard.

Comment: Doesn't work sorry. What am I supposed to do once there? I've tried resetting, that doesn't help...

Comment: @WebDev: Remove the key binding for that key.

Comment: Try assigning that key to any command to see which command it's already assigned to, then select that command in the list and remove the binding.

Comment: Forgot to test this out. It worked, thanks. It was set to Edit.AssignAlignment